# When making dictionaries in a loop, how do I write the data to a CSV when the keys can change in each loop iteration?

Tags: python

I'm scraping from a website. In this case, `trs` is a list of `<tr>` elements read by BeautifulSoup4.

My scraper goes through a website's web pages one by one. Each web page has a bunch of `<tr>` elements. Here's what the scraper looks like when extracting data from each page.

```
data = {}
for tr in trs:
  data[tr.find_all('td')[0].text] = tr.find_all('td')[1].text
```

I want the first `<td>` for each `<tr>` to be a header in the CSV I want to write. Trouble is, the first `<td>` elements in each page aren't always the same.

One page can have this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Fruit</td>
  <td>Apple</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Vegetable</td>
  <td>Squash</td>
</tr>
```

While another page could look like this

```
<tr>
  <td>Fruit</td>
  <td>Orange</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Vegetable</td>
  <td>Celery</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Origin</td>
  <td>Canada</td>
</tr>
```

When I write to a file after filling the `data` dictionary in each page, I append to CSV like this:

```
 with open('file.csv','a') as f:
        wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data.keys())
        if not os.path.exists('file.csv'): 
          wr.writeheader()       
        wr.writerow(data)
```

This does not write correctly when the program encounters a dictionary with keys not already written as headers to the output CSV.

Comment: If you are only writing your header when you first create the file, you probably want to have a list of known keys for the file.  Then pass that list as keys, then use list comprehension to create a new data row with blank entries for the not-used keys for that particular row. e.g. `wr.writerow([(data[x] if x in data else "") for x in all_keys])`

Answer (score 1):

CSV files dont work like this. It maps the headers to the position of each value in each row. So `header[0]` is the key for `row[n][0]`. So you can't have mismatched values being added to a csv with headers from a different dataset.

You need to grab all the data first before you even start to write the csv file.

```
data = {}
for trs in page:
    for tr in trs:
        data[tr.find_all('td')[0].text] = tr.find_all('td')[1].text

with open('file.csv', 'w+') as fp:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=data.keys())
    wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(data)
```